# Windows Phone Background Transfer and 206 Partial Response

Tags: c#, .net, windows-phone-7

I have a problem with the background transfer service in C# on a Windows Phone app I am developing.

When I download a large file for which the server responds with a 206 partial response on HTTP, the download doesnt work and changes its status to "completed" without downloading anything.

At http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh202959(v=vs.92).aspx the documentation states that the 206 signals a succesful download, which would make me believe that 206 is possible with Background transfer service. But on my app, I am not able to verify this.

Anyone else got experience with the problem?

Comment: What is the size of the file you're trying to download ? There's a 20MB limit for cell connections, and 100MB limit for WiFi.

Answer (score 2):

Ah I already have the answer...

206 works in general, but checking the status code is not enough in order to determine the result of a transfer. In addition to the statuscode, one should check if TransferError is null.